# GPS Tracking - MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES "hint" issue in android 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Tags: java, android, gps, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a problem in my GPS Tracking app.

I'm sending a sms message to users predefined contact every `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES` with his location.

It works really well, but when I tried it on Samsung Galaxy running on Android 2.3.5 platform it started updating every meter, (`MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES` was 1 meter) when the user was walking  (about 200 messages :)), I't works really well on ICS and JB, I couldn't find any documentation on these "hints".

As far as I understand `MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1` by default means that I wish to update every `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES` even if the user hasn't moved. And as I said it worked exactly in this logic on other platforms.

I can include some of my code but for now don't see any point in that, I tested it for a while and it works just fine, but a few days ago I installed it on Gingerbread and it's acting really weird.

Some know anything about that issue? Or maybe a way to solving it?

Comment: @Pratik Thanks for your efforts to improve SO by editing posts. However, there's really no reason for the bold emphasis you seem [to](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2100140) [introduce](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2100125) [in](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2102452) [various](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2102324) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2092324). It only introduces noise and can actually be [considered actively harmful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158564/169503).