# android valueanimator for relativelayout with textview inside is laggy

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-animation

I am *trying to animate changes of layout width*. The layout element I'm trying to animate is RelativeLayout. It contains TextView which is positioned with the rule ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM. I'm creating everything from code by extending RelativeLayout viewgroup.

**The following is a part of constructor:**

```
1    title = new TextView(c);
2    LayoutParams tvParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
3    tvParams.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
4    title.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
5    title.setText(this.feed.title);
6    this.addView(title);
```

**And this is ValueAnimator:**

```
mScaleX = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mParamsOriginal.width, mParamsLarge.width);
mScaleX.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
mScaleX.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = val;
        requestLayout();
    }
});
```

The thing is then I comment rows 2-4 and just put TextView on the layout it works just fine. Otherwise profiler says it causes constant re-measurement of the view and the device spends 90% of processor time on it.

So, is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Pratik Thanks ([**again**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521028/gps-tracking-min-time-bw-updates-hint-issue-in-android-2-3-gingerbread#comment23721285_16521028)) for your efforts to improve SO by editing posts. However, there's (**again**) really no reason for the bold emphasis you [seem](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2107429) [to](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2107410) [introduce](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2107295) in various posts. It only introduces noise and can actually be considered actively harmful.

Comment: @Xavi López thanks for suggestion i will not make bold texts next time and will try to edit only the posts having scatter code..!